# Difference between two rows in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table in the following format.

[image]
How do I take the difference between the sum of monthly spend across months when the storeID, membership_type are the same. Example output is provided below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LAG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lag) to get the value of the previous row in BigQuery:

```
SELECT 
  STOREID,
  MEMBERSHIP_TYPE,
  yyyy_mm,
  SUM_MONTHLY_SPEND, 
  IFNULL(LAG(SUM_MONTHLY_SPEND) OVER (PARTITION BY STOREID ORDER BY yyyy_mm ASC) - SUM_MONTHLY_SPEND, 0) AS MONTHLY_SPEND_DIFF
FROM dataset.table
```